# Linq Query to display string from XML in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, textbox

I'm trying to make a Linq query that will retrieve a string value from an XML file and place it in a TextBox. I think I need to use `FirstorDefault()`, but I can't figure out how to use it properly. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
var comm = from comment in xdoc.Descendants("string")                   
           where comment.Attribute("id").Value == tagBox.Text
           select comment.Element("comment").Value;

textBox.Text = comm; //Essentially
```

Basically, my XML file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <string id = "STRING_ID1">
        <element1 />
        <comment> Some string </comment>
        ...
    </string>
</root>
```

In the first code snippet, tagBox refers to another TextBox that has a string in it which was originally pulled from the `id` attribute of my `string` element. The idea is to scan the XML for the matching ID, and simply put the value of the `comment` element in the `textBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change

```
textBox.Text = comm;
```

to

```
textBox.Text = comm.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: comm is an XElement, not an IEnumerable<XElement> because he is using Element("comment").

Comment: Actually comm IS an IEnumerable<XElement>, and that was my issue.

Comment: @Dave: It's actually `IEnumerable<string>`... it was projected to the `Value` of the `XElement`.

Comment: @DaveShaw: No, `comm` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. `comment.Element("comment").Value` is only in the `select` part of the linq query!

Answer (score 1):

Usage of FirstOrDefault would be as follows

```
var str = (from str in xdoc.Descendants("string")                   
           where str.Attribute("id").Value == tagBox.Text
           select str).FirstOrDefault();

if(str != null)
{
    textBox.Text = str.Element("comment").Value;
}
else
{
    textBox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Is .Value == tagBox.Text valid in the LINQ expression?  I would have thought .Contains(tagBox.Text) would be the way to put run-time values into the query.

Comment: @DaveShaw, you're right, I forgot to remove it. The whole semantics of the code weren't right anyway so I changed it all around.

Comment: @Tim: they're both possible, but they are semantically different. "==" is exact match, and ".Contains()" would be more of a wildcard match. If you want to specify culture and have an exact match I'd use ".Equals()"

Comment: @Mr Happy - thanks for the info. I didn't realize the differences. Good stuff to know.